# Javascript: Compare values in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently learning JavaScript and completed some courses on Codecademy and Codeschool. I now know a little bit about how you write functions in JavaScript. I'm familiar with the if else statements etc, but there is one thing that I just can't get the hang on and that's why I'm hoping you  can help me with it and explain how it works so I can learn from it and use it myself in the future. I've searched a whole day yesterday and also tried a lot of things but it just doesn't work.

I have a table which contains some values (jsfiddle included), these values are not static as they are in the example but will change everyday. 
Basically what it is: it's a table which shows how many hours someone has to work and how many hours he had work. These values need to be compared to see if there is any difference. If there is a difference there should be a X in the checked row.

In the JSfiddle I've put some JavaScript that doesn't work. But that's the idea I had about how I should be implementing it (I'm quite positive that it is something in that direction, but again I'm still a beginner).

The thing that I still don't quite understand in JavaScript is how I implement this code in my HTML page so that it works. I don't know how to get a certain value from the table inside my comparison function.. if that makes sense?

Anyway, this is the code http://jsfiddle.net/3JDQQ/1/

```
    window.onload = function check(a, b){ /* a and b should represent Hours a and Hours b, this hasnt been declarated */
    for(i = 1; i <= id.length; i++){ /* id.lenght isnt a value I've declarated.  */
        if( a != b ){
            /* place nothing at check */
        } else {
            /* place a X at check */
        }
    }
}
```

Click the fiddle for the whole code.
The values that are put in there are static, but they are going to be dynamic. So I need a function that goes through these numbers every time I load the page.

Answer (score 1):

A good way of visualising the script you will write is to say how it should work.

For example:

> I need to iterate over each table row and compare value x in column 1
>   to value y in column 2 and output the difference into column 3.

Once we have that visualised we can begin to write our function:

```js
function compareCellValues() {

  var rows = $("#comparisonTable").find("tbody tr"); //returns all table rows

  rows.each(function() { //iterate over each row.

    var thisRow = $(this), //this is the current row
        hoursA = thisRow.find(".hoursA"), //this is the first value
        hoursB = thisRow.find(".hoursB"); //this is the second value

    if (hoursA.text() !== hoursB.text()) {
      thisRow.find(".check").text("X");
    }

    thisRow.find(".difference").text(parseInt(hoursA.text()) - parseInt(hoursB.text()));

  });

}

window.onload = compareCellValues();
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}
tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 0;
}
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="comparisonTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Hours a</th>
      <th>Hours b</th>
      <th>Diffrence</th>
      <th>Check</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td class="hoursA">3</td>
      <td class="hoursB">1</td>
      <td class="difference"></td>
      <td class="check"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td class="hoursA">3</td>
      <td class="hoursB">3</td>
      <td class="difference"></td>
      <td class="check"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td class="hoursA">3</td>
      <td class="hoursB">2</td>
      <td class="difference"></td>
      <td class="check"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td class="hoursA">3</td>
      <td class="hoursB">3</td>
      <td class="difference"></td>
      <td class="check"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've used jQuery for simplicity:

The difference value is now calculated based on the `hours a` and `hours b` values.

Also try to name your functions so that the name reflects the function they will perform. Just calling it check is too generic as you might have more things you want to check in the future.

Comment: Awesome! I've also tried it the Jquery way but couldn't make it work. Thanks for this it really helped! Do you maybe know how to get the "X" check correct in Jquery? I know how to do it in Javascript now but I'm curious how this will work with jquery. Thanks alot!

Comment: Yep its easy, just compare the cached values and output the X if it's needed. I've updated my fiddle example.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! It does make more sense now :D

Answer (score 0):

You should define your function outside and then call it inside `window.onload`

```
function check(a, b){ /* a and b should represent Hours a and Hours b, this hasnt been declarated */
    for(i = 1; i <= id.length; i++){ /* id.lenght isnt a value I've declarated.  */
        if( a != b ){
            /* place nothing at check */
        } else {
            /* place a X at check */
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() { check(a,b); } // call it here.
```

Comment: Ah Thanks I should have known that. A bit sloppy of me. Not the answer to my question but still thanks for noticing ;-)

Comment: That's not quite accurate, is it? `window.onload = check(a,b);` will just set `window.onload` to the output of `check(a,b)`. Since `check(a,b)` has no return statement, that will be undefined. I think you meant `window.onload=function(){check(a,b)};`?

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7aW4/)**

```
function check(){
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var difference;

    for(var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
        difference = (table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML*1) - (table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML*1);
        table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML = difference;
        table.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML = difference == 0 ? '' : 'X';
    }
}

window.onload = check;
```

Notes:

- Removed the inline `onload` because it is set in the JavaScript
- Moved `check()` to a hoisted function and assigned it to `window.onload`, to be called when the page loads
- I gave the table an ID just for the simplicity of getting a handle on it for this demo, but you can use any means you want to get the table (for example by class name).
- It loops through the table rows, starting at `1` so the header is skipped.
- The `*1` seen in the code is casting the string content of the cell to a number to do the subtraction.

---

jQuery version for completeness:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ke7de/)

```
$(function(){
    var table = $('#mytable'), difference;

    table.find('tbody > tr').each(function(){
        difference = ($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text()*1) - ($(this).find('td:eq(3)').text()*1);
        $(this).find('td:eq(4)').text(difference);
        $(this).find('td:eq(5)').text(difference == 0 ? '' : 'X');
    });
});
```

Note: if you want to replace the X with an image, use `.html()` instead of `.text()`, or append the image element.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I can work with this! When I look at your code I quite understand it. Didn't knew about the table.row[i].cells etc part. But that way you can specify a certain cell in a table. very nice!
Is it also possible to create an image at cell 5?  will that be:
table.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML = difference == 0 ? '' : '<img src=#></img>'; ? :)

Comment: Yes that will work because we are setting the raw HTML of the cell, so you can put anything you want there (providing its valid HTML).

Comment: No problem, see updated answer - added a jQuery version.